# How to fix broken repository information?

Tags: updates, update-manager, synaptic

I have the small red cross icon in my indicator applet, and upon hovering it says that *An error occurred while checking for updates.* Because of this, I can't edit the selected repositories through **synaptic**, which refuses to open the dialog and instead just tries to update the package list.

```
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [197B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementaryart/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementaryart/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en_GB
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_GB
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/nikount/orta-desktop/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/nikount/orta-desktop/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_GB
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/stk/dev/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/stk/dev/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_GB
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en_GB
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en_GB
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en_GB
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en_GB
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [197B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main Translation-en_GB
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe i386 Packages
Get:4 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,076B]
Get:6 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [735B]
Fetched 4,899B in 4s (1,060B/s)
Reading package lists...
```

Comment: Your output for update seems to be fine.How do you say that your repository is broken??

Comment: Well, it says that the update failed ... nvm, I'm reinstalling.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to cut out the "middle-man" tools and work with commands that are invoked on your behalf:

```
 sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get update 
 # you may need to repeat the update if it complains
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Any errors generated by these commands would be most informative when appended to your original question. If the `check` fails, do as it instructs or stop and post your result.

Comment: those work fine, I've tried them out already (and the output is posted above)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found an updated /etc/apt/sources.list file that differed from the previous one in that it used http://76.73.4.58/ubuntu instead of us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.  When I replaced the newest sources.list file with the old one, the apt-get upgrade worked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust your sources.list file then run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Those `ignore` claims are because you may still have a current domain still listed like `us.archive.ubuntu.com`

Just make sure in `/etc/apt/sources.list` you have `http://old.releases.ubuntu.com` for all the repositories.

Here is a video URL of my fix I had to test:
https://youtu.be/dDWwcW5e6eI